# How to get a single value from one record from a query into a field

Tags: php

In my system, I have plenty of instances of code like the following:

```
$value = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(price) as total from items WHERE a=1 AND b=2"));
```

Then `$value` is used later in the code and has the total price calculated from the array

I'm trying to replicate this in a new piece of code as follows:

```
$recent_sale_id = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id as id FROM items where item_code='$item_code' and status='BULK-ITEM-SALE' order by sold_at DESC LIMIT 1"));
```

The query works when run directly against the database (of course replacing $item_code with the item code).  But `$recent_sale_id` then just has the value 'Array'.

I'm wondering two things:

1. What am I doing wrong?  My code seems to be exactly the same as the other code that works correctly.
2. Is there a simpler way to get a value from a query into a field, without using a function that seems like it will create an array?  Is there a more suitable `mysqli_fetch*` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $recent_sale_id is returning a array in this case, that means it is of array type and in terms of getting data from mysql query often it comes in array format though you have added a limit 1.

One thing you can do to get the value is try **$recent_sale_id[0]** for the actual output.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you could access `$value` as a number because it is also an array. In the first case you would need to use either `$value[0]` or `$value['total']` to get the result; in the second either `$recent_sale_id[0]` or `$recent_sale_id['id']`. You can use either form because [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array) by default returns arrays indexed both by column number and column name.

Unfortunately the MySQLi interface does not have an equivalent to PDO's [`fetchColumn`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn) which allows you to directly fetch the value of a single column from a row in a result set.

Comment: Theoretically you can't access $value as a number but somehow this does work in the instances built for me by my developer.  I have no idea how it works, but I'll avoid replicating this coding method as it's obviously not good.
I was actually trying to use $recent_sale_id['id'] and it wasn't working but I was using it directly in another insert query.  I found that if I first passed it to a variable then used that, it worked perfectly.  Cheers.

Comment: @user3458333 if you were trying to use `$recent_sale_id['id']` directly in a string you probably needed to enclose it in `{}` to make it work e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id={$recent_sale_id['id']}"`